# Dart - GroupBy with nested lists

Tags: list, dart, group-by

Could use a Dart hero. Kinda new so let me try to explain short but correctly

I have the following object structure

- Client has a `List<Project>`
- Project has a `List<Registration>`
- Registration has a field date which is of type DateTime

```
class Client {

  String id;
  String name;
  String hexColor;
  List<Project> projects;

}

class Project {

  String id;
  String name;
  List<Registration> registrations;

}

class Registration {

  String id;
  String description;
  DateTime date;
  int minutesWorked;

}
```

So currently I have a `List<Client>` but I want to do a GroupBy based on the Registration.date value... how to do a groupBy with a nested list?

### Expected output:

```
[
  2020-01-01 00:00:00.000: [Instance of Client, Instance of Client, Instance of Client], 
  2020-01-02 00:00:00.000: [Instance of Client]
]
```

how on earth should this be pulled off!

Comment: Can you add some test code which creates the different objects and the relation between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```dart
Map<DateTime, List<Client>> clientsByRegsitrationDate(Iterable<Client> clients) {
  var result = <DateTime, List<Client>>{};
  for (var client in clients) {
    for (var registration in client.registrations) {
      result.putIfAbsent(registration.date, () => []).add(client);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

This assumes that all registration dates for the same client are different, otherwise the same client can end up in a list more than once.
If you want to avoid that, maybe:

```dart
Map<DateTime, List<Client>> clientsByRegsitrationDate(Iterable<Client> clients) {
  var result = <DateTime, List<Client>>{};
  for (var client in clients) {
    for (var registration in client.registrations) {
      var list = result.putIfAbsent(registration.date, () => []);
      if (list.isEmpty || !identical(list.last, client)) list.add(client);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Or just use sets instead of lists to collect the clients:

```dart
Map<DateTime, Set<Client>> clientsByRegsitrationDate(Iterable<Client> clients) {
  var result = <DateTime, List<Client>>{};
  for (var client in clients) {
    for (var registration in client.registrations) {
      result.putIfAbsent(registration.date, () => {}).add(client);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

That also avoids double-counting clients if they occur more than once in `clients`.

Comment: Thank you for giving multiple answers, since it missed some context on my end! you did skip the Project list but I added it in by just adding another for loop. This totally works now :)

Comment: Ack, my bad. Yes, one more loop would do it.